# Spark collect() result has incorrect length under standalone mode

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I run PySpark job in two way:

1. Local mode through IPython
2. Standalone mode through spark-submit

There is a RDD like:

`training_vector = training.map(lambda x : ... ).filter(lambda x : ...).map(lambda x : ...)`

Then I collect the different column,

`sparseData = training_vector.map(lambda x : x[1]).collect()`

`targetData = training_vector.map(lambda x : x[2]).collect()`

In IPython local mode, two printed values are the same, it's looks good.

`print len(sparseData)
print len(targetData)`

But, after I write the same code to a *.py file, and call `spark-submit --master spark://ip:7077 *.py`, the length of sparseData and targetData are slightly different. (ex. 165655 and 165662)

I've been tried several different datasets which ended with similar situation. The standalone cluster has two workers. Does anyone has the same problem?

Thanks.

Comment: This is too broad to answer without a minimum reproducible example !

Comment: I would guess that it has something to do with the fact that when running locally, you only have 1 worker and hence the order is always determined by the same worker, while in the standalone with the 2 workers you mentioned, the order can be changed due to the orders of the workers.

Comment: I guess data is not the problem, it should be the problem about standalone mode. But I don't know way this might happen under two workers? Thanks for your reply.